# Android vs Multiple Display

Tags: android, screen, tablet

I am developing an Android App @ 1.6 API level. I need to adjust my layout for every Device for which I am deciding to treat some of the layout object by programmatically and some by designing multiple drawable/ layout.  As I see my application is not looking good in Tablets e.g., Amazon kindle fire. 1024 x 768 [169 ppi]

My question is that if I design multiple images to handle multiple screen sizes i.e., hdp | xhdp | Md., my application size will more large. I have approx 30 to 40 such type of images.

What should I do for it?

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is inevitable that the more use of images, the more app size is. But I think you can reduce that using some smart ideas.

1. Use always PNG images instead of JPGs
2. Try to use Nine Patch PNG. ([How to Draw Nine Patch](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html))
3. If you target Tablets I think a separate App will be nice. Because in Tablet people are normally expecting rich UI.

Comment: Thanks Sadesh.. not a bad idea, please tell me.. how could i restrict screen sizes in API 4. is their any way to handle by MANIFEST file.

Comment: Yeah sure.. See this link : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html